# Unable to remove 2003 DC from domain environment

Tags: windows, domain, active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

I'm testing the upgrade of our a domain environment from 2003 to 2012; Our environment consists of one DC (currently 2003 but will be upgraded to 2012 with this exercise).

I've transferred all FSMO roles, tested machine login, everything works. Windows clients are able to connect to the 2012 domain and environment functions properly even when 2003 was turned off.

My final step is to demote the 2003 dc to be able to upgrade the forest and domain functional levels. I run dcpromo on the 2003 dc and I get the error:

> The network path was not found. If this computer is connected to the network via a remote access service (RAS) connection, ensure that file and printer sharing for Microsoft networks is enabled for that connection

The 2012 server has inherited services previously operating on the 2003 DC (Active directory domain services, DNS and DHCP

Comment: Try looking with procmon on what DCpromo is trying to hit and receives 'PATH_NOT_FOUND' error?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to solve my own issue. I could view network shares on the primary domain controller (server 2012). When i sorted that out, all went well.

Comment: I'd suggest you write down and answer and accept it so it doesn't stay here on stackexchange as 'unanswered' then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I managed to solve my own issue. At the time this issue was in place, I couldn't view network shares on the primary domain controller (server 2012). This was due to a GPO which i wasn't aware of which was blocking file and print sharing feature. When that was sorted out, all went well and I was able to demote DC gracefully.